# Building a setup project from bat file

Tags: .net, msbuild, batch-file, windows-installer

I want to build a setup project using a bat file and want to generate msi. I tried building using MSBuild.exe like below

```
@echo off
call %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe C:\Setup1\Setup1.sln
```

But it seems MSBUILD doesn't support setup projects. Is there any other idea to build the setup project using bat file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Devnev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) is what you're after.

The following command builds setup project *Setup1* in *C:\Setup1\Setup1.sln* in release configuration:

```
>devenv C:\Setup1\Setup1.sln /build Release /project Setup1
```

Or you can build it directly:

```
>devenv C:\Setup1\Setup1\Setup1.vdproj /build Release
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build installer projects in msbuild if you wrap the devenv with the exec target:http://thepursuitofalife.com/how-to-build-vdproj-files-in-msbuild/

Comment: Link is outdated, this one could help though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512015/how-to-use-msbuild-to-build-a-visual-studio-setup-project

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Visual Studio output to verbose, build an Installation project and check the output to see what VS does to do the same (I haven't installation projects here to do it by myself, sorry).