# Msbuild not able to create Smart Device CAB Project

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, vdproj, smart-device, teamcity-7.0

I am trying to setup TeamCity 7.0 for a smart device application. My visual studio solution contains two projects:

1. SmartRead -> The mobile application
2. SmartReadInstaller -> A Smart Device CAB Project for creating CAB file

My TeamCity configuration seems to build the SmartRead application successfully and create the necessary artifacts. But, it seems MSBuild is not able to handle the SmartReadInstaller project. The TeamCity build logs says:

> vddproj is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built.

Here is the complete build log for reference:

```
[11:46:10]Checking for changes
[11:46:10]Publishing internal artifacts
[11:46:10]Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[11:46:10]Clean build enabled: removing old files from C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e252314f72f0d569
[11:46:10]Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e252314f72f0d569
[11:46:10]Updating sources: server side checkout
[11:46:11]Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e252314f72f0d569 /msbuildPath:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
[11:46:11]in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e252314f72f0d569
[11:46:13]SmartRead.sln.teamcity: Build target: TeamCity_Generated_Build (3s)
[11:46:13][SmartRead.sln.teamcity] TeamCity_Generated_Build (3s)
[11:46:13][TeamCity_Generated_Build] MSBuild (3s)
[11:46:13][MSBuild] SmartRead.sln: Build target: Rebuild (2s)
[11:46:13][SmartRead.sln] ValidateSolutionConfiguration
[11:46:13][ValidateSolutionConfiguration] Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
[11:46:13]SmartRead\SmartRead.csproj: Build target: Rebuild (2s)
[11:46:13][SmartRead.sln] Rebuild (2s)
[11:46:16][Rebuild] CallTarget
[11:46:16][CallTarget] SmartReadInstaller:Rebuild
[11:46:16][SmartReadInstaller:Rebuild] Warning
[11:46:16][Warning] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e252314f72f0d569\SmartRead.sln warning MSB4078: The project file "SmartReadInstaller\SmartReadInstaller.vddproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built.
[11:46:16]Process exited with code 0
[11:46:16]Publishing internal artifacts
[11:46:16][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[11:46:16]Publishing artifacts
[11:46:16]Build finished
```

Please note that I am using Visual Studio (sln) runner for building my application. How do I fix this? How do I build the CAB files for my project?

Answer (score 2):

MSBuild does not support VS deployment projects. You may want to consider moving your installers to [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org) as from the next version of Visual Studio deployment projects will become [obsolete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx).

For the current projects build using [Devenv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870013/147211).

Comment: But can WiX be used for making CAB files?

Comment: Not directly, but using [Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab](http://codesupport.wordpress.com/tag/microsoft-deployment-compression-cab-dll/)